# How to reset counter for un-numbered subsections?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, theorems

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\subsection*{1}

\begin{theorem}
blah is blah
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
bloo is bloo
\end{theorem}

\subsection*{2}

\begin{theorem}
bleh is bleh
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
blih is blih
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

This shows up as:

```
1. 

Theorem 0.1. blah is blah

Theorem 0.2. bloo is bloo

2. 

Theorem 0.3. bleh is bleh

Theorem 0.4. blih is blih
```

How can I reset the counter so that in my second un-numbered subsection, Theorem 0.3 is reset to Theorem 0.1 (and also make Theorem 0.4 as Theorem 0.2)?

(I put un-numbered subsections because for this particular documentclass, the sections are centered which I don't like, so I start off by using subsections, but the subsection numbering starts with 0.1, and I want it to start with 1. so I un-numbered the subsections and put in my own numbers.)

Comment: If you don't like centered sections then change their format or change the class instead of creating such a silly and illogical document structure.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "change their format" and I can't change the class because it's useful for every other aspect of my document, except this one particular thing.

Comment: You can redefine the look of sections if you don't like the current look. Much better then dubious hacks which will lead to more and more problems.

Comment: You can do that rather easily with the `titlesec` option. Which us this class you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand what you are asking as you seem to be saying that you want two theorem 0.1s an two theorem 0.2s. This does not make sense to me, so I think that you probably want something like this:

[image]

To do this I have defined a fake `\section` command that uses a `mysection` counter, which is also used to number the theorems.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcounter{mysection}
\let\realsection=\section
\renewcommand\section[1]{\refstepcounter{mysection}%
  \subsection*{\themysection.\space #1}
}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[mysection]

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{theorem}
blah is blah
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
bloo is bloo
\end{theorem}

\section{Second section}

\begin{theorem}
bleh is bleh
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
blih is blih
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

changing the format of the `\section` command is trivial, and a much better approach (as pointed out by ulrike fischer) than skipping that level and using `\subsection`.

this is the definition of `\section` in `amsart.cls`:

```
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\scshape\centering}}
```

just remove the `\centering` command:

```
\makeatletter
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\scshape}}
\makeatother
```

if you would rather have some font style other than small caps, you can change that
at the same time, say to `\bfseries`.

an alternative method of changing just parts of a command definition is provided by
the command `\patchcmd` from the package `etoolbox`; refer to the documentation for details.